# ReferenceError: product is not defined

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm trying to fetch the data , but when i console it.I' getting the data but in rendering it's not working in front end its showing  product is not defined.

```
app.get('/profile/profile/dashboard/update/:id',function (req,res,next) {
           //console.log("hello "+req.params.id);
    Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(product=>{

        console.log("hello check please "+ product);
    });

    res.render('update.ejs',{ product: product });
});
```

> update.ejs file

```
<% if (product._id) { %>
        <tbody>
        <td><input type="text" value="<%= product.name %>" required></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" required></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" required></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" required></td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="submit"></td>
        </tbody>
        <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes problem with your code is rendering is placed outside of the find one method. Put it inside the braces like.

```
app.get('/profile/profile/dashboard/update/:id',function (req,res,next) {
           //console.log("hello "+req.params.id);
    Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(product=>{

        console.log("hello india "+ product);
        res.render('update.ejs',{ product: product });
    });
});
```

Comment: If i use async await method then ??

Comment: yes, for every async method you have to put render inside .

Comment: @EasyFreeNotes you could indeed use async await. Just add the `async` keyword to the function declaration (`async function(req,res)`..) and then use await in the findOne `const product = await Product.findOne(...);   res.render(...)` will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to render the data before the findOne is finished. `findOne` is asynchronic function and that is why the log works for you.

Move `res.render` inside the `then` scope:

```
Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(product=>{

        console.log("hello check please "+ product);
        res.render('update.ejs',{ product: product });
    });
```